# Override some Methodes of VirtualPathProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, virtualpathprovider

I want to use the default implemented **VirtualPathProvider** of ASP.Net MVC Web Application.

In other words I want to inherit my own VirtualPathProvider  from default Asp.net VirtualPathProvider and just override the **GetCacheKey** Method.

What should I do?

Anyone can help?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your custom virtual path provider class, overriding the method you want, and then call [`HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.registervirtualpathprovider.aspx) from within `Application_Start` (defined in `global.asax.cs`) to install it:

```
protected void Application_Start() {
    HostingEnvirontment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(new MyVPProvider());
}
```

Comment: Thanks jon, But as you know VirtualPathProvider is an abstract class. So I think I should implement other methods too. or am I wrong??? can you please tell me about this?

Comment: Oh my... That was a really stupid question. I didn't know that abstract classes can have none abstract methods...

Comment: @abzarak: Of course you should implement `FileExists` and `GetFile`. But yes, there are no abstract methods.

Comment: So is there not any way to just inherit from default VirtualPathProvider ?

Comment: I noticed that there is not any abstract method to be implemented. So I think it's enough for me to override the only method I want... is it true?

Comment: @abzarak: Yes, but depending on what you want to do you may also need to override other methods. Example with `System.Object`: you are never forced to override `object.Equals`, but when you do you also have to override `object.GetHashCode`.